# Google map ios sdk info window only appear on 2 taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, xcode7.2

I am using google maps ios sdk.
I have created a custom xib file for info window.

The issue I am getting is whenever I tap on a marker it the google map automatically makes the marker in center and then on next tap `info window` is displayed.

What I want is the tapped **marker** should display `info window` on immediately instead of tap on second time

Here is the code I'm using

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {

    if (marker != self.pointMarker) {
        if (!self.shuttleInfoWindow) {
            [self initShuttleInfoWindowObject];
        }

        Shuttle* shuttle = (Shuttle*)marker.userData;
        if (shuttle) {
            [self.shuttleInfoWindow setCurrentShuttle:shuttle];

        }
        self.shuttleInfoWindow.isInfoWindowDisplayed = YES;
        return self.shuttleInfoWindow;
    }
    return nil;


}


- (void)initShuttleInfoWindowObject {
    self.shuttleInfoWindow =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.shuttleInfoWindow setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                0,
                                                self.shuttleInfoWindow.frame.size.width,
                                                self.shuttleInfoWindow.frame.size.height)];
    self.shuttleInfoWindow.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try writing this delegate :

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView*)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker*)marker
{
    [mapview setSelectedMarker:marker];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: ok good. can you tell me how we can center the map on selected marker and then display info window. Both task in a single tap

Comment: you can set  , camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:currentLoc.coordinate.latitude
                                                     longitude:currentLoc.coordinate.longitude
                                                          zoom:17.0];
                [_viewMap animateToCameraPosition:camera];

Comment: @RahulVyas : if you have worked on VIdeos then can you please help in this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242159/how-to-add-animation-on-image-change-while-create-video-using-images

Comment: Tried setting camera but no luck. When we center the camera then again info window opens in second tap

Comment: we did that but we dont won't to use UIImageview

Comment: first write  [_viewMap setSelectedMarker:markerInit]; this and then set camera position. try it please if it works